# python - laço estranho

Tags: python, while

Estou quase terminando o meu aplicativo. Nos momentos finais do código estou travando em um laço que eu não consigo resolver.

```
# O programa pede para o usúario inserir uma data no formato dd/mm/aa,
# e efetua uma série de cálculos simples até chegar num número menor que 22
# e somente composto por unidades. Os cálculos são basicamente pegar o maior número,
# da data definida pelo usuário e somar seu algarismos, depois soma-se ao restante dos 
# números que compõe a data. Por exemplo: 
# data: 23/11/1956 => 23 + 11 + 21 = 55 ==>  5 + 11 +  21 = 37 ==> 5 + 11 + 3 = 19, 
# como 19 é uma dezena, fazemos 1 + 9 = 10  e novamente 1 + 0 = 1. Neste caso, os valores 
# retornados seriam: 19, 10, 01 e cada número é associado há uma sorte.  

#importa os módulos necessários

import datetime   

#declara variáveis globais

dataInput = ""
dataLi = []
somaAlg = 0

def validaData(dataInput):   #valida a data
    while True:
        try:
            dataInput = str(input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': "))
            date_formatted = datetime.datetime.strptime(dataInput, '%d/%m/%Y')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Error")
    dataLi = dataInput.split("/")  #transforma a string em uma lista, afim de efetuar os cálculos no futuro
    return dataLi                       

def calcula_arcano(revDataLi) : #função para somar o maior número da data, que nesta altura 
                                       # já é uma lista.

    somaAlg = 0
    adc = 0
    maior = max(revDataLi)

    while maior != 0 :
        adc =  maior % 10
        somaAlg = somaAlg + adc
        maior =  maior  // 10
    return somaAlg

def main():
    arcList = []
    dataLi = validaData(dataInput)
    revDataLi = list(reversed(dataLi))                      # coloca a lista em reverso 
    revDataLi = [int(data) for data in revDataLi]    


    total = sum(revDataLi)      # soma os numeros dá lista afim de checa-lo


# 22 é um número um tanto quanto ábitrário, tem a ver com "range" das sortes.
# este laço tem com objetivo "decompor" a lista até que o total seja 22 ou menos.

    while total >=22 :  
        somaAlg = calcula_arcano(revDataLi)
        revDataLi = [somaAlg if data == max(revDataLi) else data for data in revDataLi]
        total = sum(revDataLi)
    else:
        arcList.append(total)
        y = 0
        aux = total
        while total >= 10 and total < 22 :  #este laco tem como objetivo reduzir o total a unidades,
            aux=str(total)
            y = sum(int(i) for i in aux)
            total = y
        else:
            arcList.append(int(aux))  # para começar a compor a lista de retorno(arcList)
            arcList.append(total)
            print(arcList)
            print("O seu arcano pessoal é o ", arcList)  #final temporário, o desfecho do aplicativo
                                                               # vai ser associar os número encontrados com
                                                               # uma "sorte", conselho

main()
```

As coisas começam a dar errado(acho eu, pois utilizo o Atom para escrever e ainda não peguei o jeito de debugar eficientemente direito com o Idle), neste laço aqui: `while total >= 10 and total < 22 :` em diante. Eu tenho feito testes com 3 datas diferentes:

1. `21/02/12` -> Funciona -> `arcList: 8`
2. `23/11/1956` -> Funciona -> `arcList: 19, 10, 01`
3. `31/12/2999` -> Não Funciona -> `arcList: 18, 18, 9` - deveria ser -> `18, 9`

O que pode ser esse problema? Aproveitando, se alguém tiver alguma dica sobre o código no geral e jeitos mais eficientes de testar, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: De onde vem essa datas?

Comment: Seria interessante você descrever o que o código deveria fazer de maneira geral. Por exemplo, qual é o sentido de somar os componentes de uma data (`sum(revDataLi)`)?

Comment: Marylsson, as do teste? tentei escolher casos particulares, nada de mais. @Anderson editei o código adicionando comentários

Answer (score -1):

Criei esta função que retira as barras da string para trabalhar com a data em formato de string que contém só os números ("31/12/2999" -> "31122999"). Dentro da função tem um for que varre a string e soma cada carácter dela. (3+1+1+2+2+9+9+9). Se o valor for menor ou igual a 22 ela retorna o número encontrado. Se não, ela transforma o número encontrado em string ("35"), zera a variável que seria retornada e entra no for novamente.

```
def numero_arcano(data):
    cond = True
    data_string = data.replace("/", "") 
    arcano = 0
    while cond == True:
        for number in data_string:
            arcano += int(number)
        if(arcano <= 22):
            cond = False
        else:
            data_string = str(arcano)
            arcano = 0
    return arcano
```

Comment: Não coloque apenas código como resposta. Explique o que o seu código faz e como ele resolve o problema da pergunta, para que tanto o autor da pergunta como futuros leitores consigam seguir a sua linha de raciocinio

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão.